# max_element on vector of pairs without "predicate"

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I want to find the max element of `vector` of `pairs`.
My criteria is: the max element  is one with highest second value of the pair.
I did this:

```
auto max_angle = std::max_element(begin(angles), end(angles),
            [](const std::pair<int, int>& left, const std::pair<int, int>& right){
            return left.second <  right.second;
        });
```

Is it possible to do it without writing a predicate? Is there any easier way for pairs since it is a std struct?

Comment: sorry edited...  I meant the third paramter of std::max_elemnt "pr _Pred"

Comment: There are 2 things you might also consider: transformation of the `vector<pair>` into `map` or splitting keys and values into separate `vector`s.

Comment: Map is not an option since I have duplicated items. two vectors is a possible solution. However, it is easier to go throw one container than two.. isn't it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't, because by default `std::pair`s are compared lexicographically, meaning element-wise left to right. As such, your solution is the simplest solution you can have.